# Did DOOM for SNES support the SNES mouse and Super Scope?

Tags: controllers, snes, doom

I have just watched a video interview with the programmer for the SNES port of DOOM:

I did not note the timestamp, but at one point he mentions how he wanted to have "as many feature icons as possible" on the box art, and said how the game supported the Super Scope, the mouse, XBAND, etc.

Afterwards, I tried to look up both videos of the mouse in action and tried to view scans of the box's front and back, but saw no mention of mouse or Super Scope support.

Shouldn't there be some video showing this off if it actually supported those controllers? It would be amazing to see how "smooth" the player moves with the mouse.

I also did not see the game listed in a list of mouse-supporting SNES games. But then why did he say that in the interview? It didn't seem like a joke to me.

Comment: The super scope Wikipedia page doesn't say its supported: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Scope#Compatible_games  The super scope didn't seem to have much popularity in general, so very few games supported it.

Answer (score 4):

Looking into the manual for DOOM (SNES Version) it clearly states that:

> This product is not designed for use with the SUPER NES MOUSE, SUPER NES SUPER SCOPE or SUPER NES MULTI-PLAYER ADAPTERS.

I found the manual virtually under [this link](https://bdjogos.com.br/manuais/211-doom-super-nintendo-manual-usa.pdf) (Website: bdjogos) and below you can see a screenshot of page 3 (page 4 if including the cover) showing the above quote.

[image]